# Start second Android activity in the background to load before bringing to front

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-activity

In my Android app, I have second activity (a Unity game) that I launch from a button click. The problem is that there is a significant loading time that it needs to go through before opening up. Once I press the button I would like it to launch in the background but have the first app still open while the second one finishes loading.

Does anybody know how to do this?
Many thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us more how your app is implemented? Two activities and one of them is a unity game? What does the game contains? How many scenes do you have in your game and which one are you launching at the beginning?

Comment: Sorry I should have said, its an android app that is a launcher for a unity project. It has 4 scenes at the moment (each one a different level). I have a button for each scene that will send a message to the unity project to open that specific scene. I essentially want to load the scene in the background and have my own "loading screen" that is visible until the unity scene has finished loading. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you should first create a `Loading Scene` inside `Unity` and launch it as first scene when starting the second `Activity` and than inside your `Loading scene` start loading in the background the level you want to show. There is no way to load the `Activity` in the background and then show it once it's ready.

And another thing, keep in mind that Unity is loading native libraries and there is no way to open it as fast as a normal Android `Activity`.